# Pattern matching dates

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having troubles trying to match a pattern of dates. Any of the following dates are legal:

```
 - 121212
 - 4 9 12
 - 5-3-2000
 - 62502
 - 3/3/11
 - 09-08-2001
 - 8 6 07
 - 12 10 2004
 - 4-16-08
 - 3/7/2005
```

What makes this date matching really challenging is that the year doesn't have to be 4 digits (a 2 digit year is assumed to be in the 21st century i.e. 02 = 2002), the month/date can either be written with a beginning 0 if it is a one digit month, and the dates may or may not be separated by spaces, dashes, or slashes.

This is what I currently have:
`/((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))[\/-]?\s*(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|([469])|(11))[\/-]?\s*(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(30)))|((2|02)[\/](([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12][0-9])))[\/-]?\s*(20[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{2}))/g`

This almost works, except right now I'm not exactly sure if I'm assuming the length of the dates and months. For example, in the case `121212`, I might be assuming the month is `1` instead of `12`. Also, for some reason when I'm printing out `$1` and `$2`, it is the same value. In the case of `121212`, `$1` is `1212`, `$2` is `1212` and `$3` is `12`. However, I just want `$1` to be `121212`.

Comment: is year "00" 2000 (technically the 20th century)

Comment: Seems to me like this is impossible to do with 100% accuracy: 11213 could be 1-12-13 or 11-2-13.  Both are valid dates.

Comment: Indeed, I guess in those cases I will just assume the date is 1-12-13. I don't need 100% accuracy, I just need to get most of the cases down.

Comment: my answer seems to have been deleted, not sure why.  it has information not in the others.

Comment: Does 1-12-13 mean 1st December 2013 or 12th January 2013? Different people will make different assumptions.

Comment: @DaveCross from the code, it is clear it is the latter

Answer (score 1):

This solution handles all of the cases that you provided. But the solution isn't foolproof because the problem has ambiguities. E.g. how do we interpret the date `12502`? Is it 1/25/02 or 12/5/02?

```
use 5.010;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @date = $line =~ /
        \A
        ([01]?\d)   # month is 1-2 digits, but the first digit may only be 0 or 1
        [ \-\/]?    # may or may not have a separator
        ([0123]?\d) # day is 1-2 digits
        [ \-\/]?
        (\d{2,4})   # year is 2-4 digits
        \z
    /x;
    say join '_', @date;
}

__DATA__
121212
4 9 12
5-3-2000
12502
3/3/11
09-08-2001
8 6 07
12 10 2004
4-16-08
3/7/2005
```

Comment: you've got "day" and "month" backward in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Your task is ambiguous, since you may not be able to tell mmd from mdd or mdccyy from mmddyy.

You left off the option for spaces or dashes in one place where you match /.

You aren't checking for leap years.

This is doable, but it's awfully easy to make a mistake; how about not trying to do it with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

The CPAN modules [Time::ParseDate](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Time-modules-2003.0211/lib/Time/ParseDate.pm) and [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.78/lib/DateTime.pm) are probably what you're looking for, except the `62502` pattern:

```
use DateTime;
use Time::ParseDate;

foreach my $str (<DATA>) {
    chomp $str;
    $str =~ tr{ }{/};

    my $epoch = parsedate($str, GMT => 1);
    next unless $epoch; # skip 62502

    my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch ( epoch => $epoch );
    print $dt->ymd, "\n";
}

__DATA__
121212
4 9 12
5-3-2000
62502
3/3/11
09-08-2001
8 6 07
12 10 2004
4-16-08
3/7/2005
```

Once you have the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.78/lib/DateTime.pm) object, you can extract `year`, `month`, and `day` information easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with based on what info you've given. It matches all possibilities, and has error checking for month/day ranges and also the year (from 1900 to 2099)

```
/(1[012]|0?\d)([-\/ ]?)([12]\d|3[01]|0?\d)\2((19|20)?\d\d)/
```